# NSCalendar returns same date component difference for two different dates

Tags: date, nscalendar

I'm calculating the difference in months and days between two dates using

```
- NSCalendar components:fromDateComponents:toDateComponents:options:
```

Interestingly I get the same result for two different days:

- `2014-07-30` - `2015-07-20`: 11 months 20 days
- `2014-07-31` - `2015-07-20`: 11 months 20 days

A gist with a full command line program to reproduce is here: https://gist.github.com/p2/a1f7ad6acc9d555ee00b

The relevant parts:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSCalendarUnit flags = NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSDateComponents *rslt = nil;

// between 7/30/2014 and 7/20/2015: 11 months 21 days
NSDateComponents *later = [NSDateComponents new];
later.year = 2015;
later.month = 7;
later.day = 20;

NSDateComponents *earlier = [NSDateComponents new];
earlier.year = 2014;
earlier.month = 7;
earlier.day = 30;

rslt = [calendar components:flags fromDateComponents:earlier toDateComponents:later options:0];
// rslt.month is 11, rslt.day is 20

// between 7/31/2014 and 7/20/2015: 11 months 20 days
earlier.day = 31;

rslt = [calendar components:flags fromDateComponents:earlier toDateComponents:later options:0];
// rslt.month is 11, rslt.day is 20
```

Can anyone explain what's going on and what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm an idiot and the computer is, once more, correct. Thanks Rob for pointing out the obvious:

> In this case, 11 months from 2014-07-30 is 2015-06-30, and 11 months from 2014-07-31 is also 2015-06-30. (after all, you wouldn't want it to be 2015-07-01).
>   20 days after this date is 2015-07-20.
>
> So the time from both 2014-07-30 and 2015-07-31 to 2015-07-20 is 11 months and 20 days.